# Why is creating a temp array with Stride illegal in an Array extension

Tags: arrays, swift, extension-methods, stride

This code throws a compiler error: "Argument type 'StrideTo' expected to be an instance of a class or class-constrained type"

```
extension Array {
    func chunks(_ chunkSize: Int) -> [[Element]] {
        let indexes = Array(stride(from: 0, to: count, by: chunkSize)) // This line won't compile
        return [[Element]]()
    }
}
```

However, if you use very similar code outside of an Array extension:

```
let array = Array(stride(from: 0, to: 20, by: 4))
```

It gives me what I would expect, an array `[0, 4, 8, 12, 16]`.

Why is illegal to create a temporary Array in a function in an Array extension? Is it somehow invoking a `stride()` instance method on the Array? If so, is there a way to tell the compiler that I want to invoke the global `stride()` function instead?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That is a bug: [SR-13847 Wrong generic used in extensions](https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-13847):

> For some reason when calling initializer in extension, compiler tries to match unrelated generics.

In your case, `Array` is interpreted as `Array<Element>`. As a workaround, you can specify the type of the index array explicitly:

```
let indexes = Array<Int>(stride(from: 0, to: count, by: chunkSize))
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply and the link to the bug report. (Voted)